# Why does a cast hold inside of a case statement?

Tags: t-sql, case

Why, when you run this, do you get *2.00* as the answer?

```
declare @temp int  = 2
select CASE WHEN @temp = 1 THEN cast(@temp as decimal(5, 2))
         WHEN @temp = 2 THEN  @temp
         ELSE NULL
    END
```

But if you run this, you get *2* as the answer when selecting just @temp2

```
declare @temp2 int = 2
select CAST(@temp2 as decimal(5,2))
select @temp2
```

Bridge is correct:

Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression. ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx))

[Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the return value has to be the same datatype for each possible output from the case statement. It considers the possible outputs, and tries to cast them all to the same type.

The first possible return value there is of type `decimal(5, 2)`, and second of type `int`. It chooses the datatype with the highest presidence that can hold both values, and automatically casts all the outputs to this for you.

Your second script is behaving as expected. You actually get two values output:

- `2.00` - which is the result of the cast in the second line
- `2` - which is the value of @temp2 - which is an int, you assigned it on the first line

Comment: Not exactly, when you swap the 2 `WHEN` statements, it should "see" the first return value being still int. So it's more like it is casted to a datatype which can hold both possibilities. No?

Comment: @tombom Yes I believe that's how it works. I guess you could end up with SQL_VARIANTs getting output if you did enough crazyness in there. I'll add your better explanation to my answer.

Comment: As Stefan said, it chooses the highest precedence, which in this case is decimal (12), as opposed to int (16). -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx

Comment: @Ryan You are right, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx My vote goes to Stefan :)

Comment: @tombom Don't write me off right away - I took the time to explain why it happens even if my explanation of which datatype chosen was slightly off. I would upvote Stefan if I hadn't already hit my daily limit! I've added both your comments to my answer - please let me know if it's still inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx
section Return Types.
The highest precedence type is taken.